# Can I have multiple display names for same app on App Store?

Tags: ios, iphone

Have searched high & low with little guidance / alternatives!

We provide an iPhone app to enterprise clients. Our single app hosts all clients in the same native app, and we want to add simplicity for the end user to find the application.

Is there a way to have multiple display names for the exact same app in the Apple App Store?

IDEALLY, user searches "Customer Name #1" in the App Store and "Customer Name #1" with Customer #1 logo is displayed...same with "Customer #2" and so forth BUT downloading either "Customer #1" or "Customer #2" will be the exact same app, code, revision...

This seems unlikely though, so other recommendations are appreciated (adding customer names in description).

Answer (score 0):

Display name is a static value.
 It will not change  with out updating latest version

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend create and submit multiple apps to AppStore, which different in icons, name and settings. The codebase may be the same. The whole process of building and even submitting multiple apps may be automated (you will need to create a tool for that, but this is not as hard as it sounds).

Comment: Also, you have to set unique different bundle for new app.

Comment: What are potential repercussions of this namely if users?  If customer downloads Customer #1 and Customer #2 app and both exactly identical with access to customer #1 features and customer #2 facilities. The app is free & users are public (not staff. It’s a geolocation solution.